# Why doesn't SublimeREPL accept undefined data types? (Issue inputting string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I am trying to provide a simple input to a program using SublimeREPL on Sublime Text. Sample code below

```
print('Please print your name')
name = input()
print(name)
```

When I try to input my name via SublimeREPL as just

```
MyNameHere
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "input_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    name = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MyNameHere' is not defined
```

however, if I input my name as a string such as

```
'MyNameHere'
```

I get no such error and the program prints my input. This program seems to work just fine in IDLE regardless of whether I define the input as a string or not. This seems to suggest to me that SublimeREPL cannot accept undefined data inputs?  Is this an issue with SublimeREPL or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: It appears that SublimeREPL  is using Python2. Please do not use Python2.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: In Python 2, `input()` evaluates the input as code and `raw_input()` gathers raw input as a string and returns it. The error you're seeing here definitely seems to be that; `'MyName'` is a string, but `MyName` is not valid code that it knows how to compile. If you meant to be using Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead. If you think you're using Python 3 as evidenced by your tag, you're not and your SublimeREPL is not configured properly and is running the wrong version. How you fix that may depend on your OS, as @MattDMo mentioned above.

Comment: To mark a problem resolved, use the "Add an Answer" button to add an answer, and then click the checkmark to accept it (note that when you answer your own question, there's a delay before the accept checkmark becomes available). _Don't_ just edit "RESOLVED" into the title, or edit the answer into the question itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the heads up - still quite new to stack overflow, so I appreciate the direction

Answer (score 0):

From a question edit:

> This issue was caused due to misconfigured sublime text using python 2.x rather than python 3.x